# Importing Contributions - Email Receipt

Tags: civicontribute, import, receipts

When importing contributions I would like receipts to go to the contacts that made the payment. What is the best approach to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You could import and tag or add to a Group, then find via Adv Search (filter by Group/Tag plus date of donation) but set to 'Display as Contributions, then use the Actions to trigger Print or Email Contribution Receipt which is described thus:

> You may choose to email receipts to contributors OR download a PDF file containing one receipt per page to your local computer by clicking Process Receipt(s).

Comment: How do you Tag on Import Contributions? For Import Contacts it works OK.

Comment: no way to Tag on a Contribution Import. Suggest you add a custom field to Contributions. Add a column to your data import to put in that custom field. then you can do a search in civi, find contacts with a contribution with the custom data, and then Tag those contacts.

Comment: I have looked at that. It opens a new can of CiviCRM worms, I'll learn in due course. Only two years experience so far!!! We do not have a website for members. All being done by separate payments via the bank that gives us payment info.

Comment: not sure which can of worms you found - worms in tomato sauce? worms and meatballs?